# Nested relations image url in paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip

I have two rails models with the relationship user has many designs.
designs has an 'has_attached_file' of paperclip.

So when I do the following for an image tag it works fine.

`@img_des = current_user.designs.first.img.url`

But can't get this to work.

`@img_des = current_user.designs.where(id: params[:id]).img.url`

Throws the following error

`` NoMethodError in DesignerController#show
undefined method `design' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_Design:0xb1ede48> ``

Any suggestions, mostly it must be due to my lack of understanding of rails nested models.

Comment: Could you please paste your modal and controller code here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For single record it's better to use `find`

```
@img_des = current_user.designs.find(params[:id]).img.url
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to make it object first rather than array as where return you an ARRAY

```
 @img_des = current_user.designs.where(id: params[:id]).first.img.url
```

Comment: I knew it was something to do with my understanding and not an issue with paperclip itself. This solved my issue.